# How to resolve StackOverflowError by changes in java code

Tags: java, stack-overflow

I am getting java.lang.StackOverflowError while using recursive function.

Actually In recursive function xml file has been parsed and if in xml file, previous xml feed url exists, then that xml again passes to same function and again in this xml file previous xml feed url exists then again passes to same function.

This process continues until it gets previous xml feed url. I am not getting error for 10,000 files but after that when again same function call happens for 10,001th file, I am getting java.lang.StackOverflowError. I want to resolve this error by changes in coding, not by increasing memory, trying to implement solution like do this recursive call for fixed batch size.

Please let me know If you can provide me better solution for StackOverflowError. Requested for part of solution code if you ever implement this kind of solution.

Regards,
Shobhit

Comment: Are you keeping all Streams open when performing this recursive call? From what I read it sounds like you can always close the current stream once a previous xml feed is found since you traverse to that found file.

Comment: Stack overflows are caused (generally I believe) when you make too many nested method calls and are typical in recursive code. Therefore make your recursion clear. Make sure you have a base case that will terminate.

Comment: read this http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072881/diagnosing-and-resolving-stackoverflowerror.html link

Comment: Do I understand correctly: you iterate over a given set of xml files/urls and within each file, you recursively follow links to urls that point to one of your already-visited files?

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff You are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I have fixed by problem by using a try/catch block. I catch StackOverflowError and store the last file processed in memory. Then, I call the method again and start from the file on which the StackOverflowError happened.

Update:
Now, I have implemented better solution for StackOverFlowError. I am running process in a batch of configurable size. For example, process will process in a batch of 100 size and if further processing is required, it will be in next batch.

Answer (score 1):

General answer as the description of your code is a bit vague:

StackOverflowError happens when you need more stack than allocated - that's trivial. Within a stack of nested method calls, be they recursive or not, every method call needs some amount of stack, determined by the number of parameters and local variables in the method. So to reduce your stack requirements, you can either have less nested method calls or have less parameters and locals in your methods. Both needs a redesign of your software.

Especially dangerous are recursive calls. If you can't tell in advance how many nested recursive calls will at most happen, the risk of getting a StackOverflowError is very high.

Your description sounds a bit like a depth-first search (implemented by recursion) in the graph formed by the urls and links. If you can change that to a breadth-first search (typically implemented by iteration), there's no reason for StackOverflow any more. Of course, both searches need a termination condition so you don't get caught in a cycle forever.